# C++ Check the length of an array with Zeros and nulls

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an int array, of let say... 1000 elements.  The user enters 128 and it fills the array as 821. Before it gets said, let me say, it has to be backwards for simplicity of other functions. To get the length I use

```
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; array1[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        count++;
    }
```

this works great.  Until they enter a number with a 0 in it, such as 0, or 100.
The array is filled as 001, but the test stops it immediately since 0 is equal to '\0'

I cant use sizeof(array1)/sizeof(*array1) because then when I go to print the array I get tons of zeros followed by the number.  It does print correctly, but its not what I want.

Any solutions?

Comment: What you need to do is convert the digits to corresponding characters.

Comment: Does it **have** to be an array? Using `vector<int>` would be much more C++ way and much less painful. `vector` has methods that can tell you both it's capacity and number of elements in it.

Comment: Why not just have a variable that tracks how many valid digits there are?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: It does have to be an array.  I also tried having a variable that tracks how many valid digits are in it, but I either did something wrong, or it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way is to fill the whole array with an invalid value (such as -1) before you use it. By saying "invalid" it can be anything except 0-9 according to your description.

```
memset(array1, -1, sizeof(array1));
// doing things
```

And why don't you just save the numbers as characters since they are from user input? Just use '0' instead of '\0' to represent the zero, so you don't have the issue. You even can use `strlen` to get the length directly if you guarantee that there is always '\0' in the end of array:

```
// array size is 1001 instead of 1000 to reserve a '\0' in the end
char array1[1001] = {'8', '2', '1'}
size_t count = strlen(array1);
```

Comment: This won't work since `array1` is a ___character array___ (I think). EDIT: I did not notice the `except 0-9` part.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is convert the digits to corresponding characters.

Lets say, you have `1230`. In your array you actually store `1 + '0'`, `2 + '0'`, `3 + '0'` and `'0'`. `'0'` being the ASCII value of the key that has `0` printed on it.

That way you will never confuse `'0'` with `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

you could dertermine the amount of digits your number has and then dynamically allocate the array with the calculated size.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches I can think of:

1. You increase the size after each element the user inputs
2. You mark the end with a number the user will never input

For example on the first case:

```
char array1[1000];
int count = 0;

while(!the_end)
{
    std::cin >> array1[count++]
}

// From now, every time you add elements to the array, increase  the "size" variable

std::cout << "Size: " << count << std::endl;
```

For the second case, there are some methods, but what I think which would be the best for you, is by fulfilling the array with the invalid value before you start to get the input from the user:

```
char array1[1000] = {-1};
// Start getting the input...

int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; array1[i] != -1; ++i)
{
    count++;
}

std::cout << "Size: " << count << std::endl;
```

**Note:** if you're stuck on this, then your code probably has some design flaws. For the design to be good, you'd be using the first approach I suggested and not trying to find the size afterwards. Or better, you could be using `std::vector` as suggested in the commentaries, or at least could have some type of "tracking" for the elements you input to the array.

Comment: Actually no, it wont, my assert functions are preventing negative numbers.

Comment: So would I just use array1[i] = 0xFF or '0xFF' or "0xFF"?  I know which slot it should belong in, I'm jsut not sure how to apply it to the array.

Comment: Then you could use `unsigned char`, and the number `0xFF`, which is the biggest value you can get from it.

Comment: You could use `array1[i] = 0xFF`, but for a `signed char`, the assertion would be triggered, as `0xFF` = `-1`, talking about 1-byte signed. That's why I suggest `unsigned char`, then `0xFF` would be `255` instead of `-1`, but you're confusing some data types here. The integer number the user sees on a console, for example, has a different value, than the own number but in the integer form, not in char.